# eclipse class path for soot

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, soot

im writing a program to get and print the call graph of a program. im using soot to try and get the call graph and i pass as an argument the java class i want to print out but when i run the program i get a message that soot cant find the class. how do i configure the eclipse class path to find the calss i want to print?

my code:

```
public class CFG extends SceneTransformer
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        if(args.length == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Syntax: java CFG [soot options]");
            System.exit(0);
        }            

        PackManager.v().getPack("wjtp").add(new Transform("wjtp.cfg", CFG.v()));

    // Just in case, resolve the PrintStream and System SootClasses.
    Scene.v().addBasicClass("java.io.PrintStream",SootClass.SIGNATURES);
        Scene.v().addBasicClass("java.lang.System",SootClass.SIGNATURES);
        soot.Main.main(args);
    }

    private static CFG instance = new CFG();

    public static CFG v() { return instance; }

    protected void internalTransform(String phaseName, Map options)
    { 
    System.out.println("Entering CFG transformer");
    System.out.println("phaseName = " + phaseName);
    System.out.println("options = " + options);
    CallGraph cg = Scene.v().getCallGraph();
    SootMethod m = Scene.v().getMainMethod();
    Iterator targets = new Targets(cg.edgesOutOf(m));
    while (targets.hasNext()) {
        SootMethod trgt = (SootMethod)targets.next();
    System.out.println(m.getName() + " -> " + trgt.getName() + ";");
    }
    System.out.println("Exiting CFG transformer");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable whole-program mode by using the -w flag. Otherwise w* packs do not get executed.

Comment: im using the soot eclipse plugin in eclipse

Comment: try running it from the command line; this leaves less room for user error

Comment: i use the line java -classpath . graph.CFG p1.myClass

Comment: it writes back transforming p1.myClass but not going into internalTransform

Comment: You need to enable whole-program mode, see above.